# Sort a list of lists in Groovy

Tags: list, sorting, groovy

Sorry if this is a straight forward thing, I'm new to Groovy. I'm trying to figure out how to sort this list on the "uses" key in each sub list,  but I can't seem to get it figured out:

```
[[name:foo, uses:2], [name:bar, uses:1], [name:baz, uses:4]]
```

I'm hoping to get the following result:

```
[[name:baz, uses:4], [name:foo, uses:2], [name:bar, uses:1]]
```

Does someone out there know how to best handle this? I checked similar questions but couldn't find anything pertaining to Groovy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to use the `sort` method

```
def sorted = lists.sort( {a, b -> b["uses"] <=> a["uses"] } )
sorted.each { 
 println it
}

// prints
// [name:baz, uses:4]
// [name:foo, uses:2]
// [name:bar, uses:1]
```

Comment: i think we answered this at the exact same time. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out...

```
sort{a,b -> b['uses'] <=> a['uses']}
```

...seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

just wanted to add a shorter version

```
[[name:'foo', uses:2], [name:'bar', uses:1], [name:'baz', uses:4]].sort{-it.uses}​​​​​
```